# WPF tab control drag 'n drop: bring tab in front behavior

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, tabcontrol

I would like to implement drag 'n drop with a tabcontrol in a way that dragging an item to tag strip brings it to front.
Which is the most efficient and non obtrusive way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void TabControl_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    TabItem item = e.Source as TabItem;
    TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
    if (item != null && tabControl != null)
    {
        if (tabControl.SelectedItem != item)
            tabControl.SelectedItem = item;
    }
}
```