# Dragging over a dragablz:TabablzControl tab to bring it to front

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, tabitem

I would like to implement a DragEnter-Event for each TabItem of my dragablz:TabablzControl. Tabs should be automatically selected when dragging a file over it.

I found two topics on stackoverflow that seem to be similar to my question:

- [Dragging over a tab to bring to front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625387/dragging-over-a-tab-to-bring-to-front)
- [WPF tab control drag 'n
  drop: bring tab in front behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439323/wpf-tab-control-drag-n-drop-bring-tab-in-front-behavior)

Unfortunately these solutions doesn't work for TabablzControl from [Dragablz](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz).

```
<dragablz:TabablzControl Name="TC_FooBar" FixedHeaderCount="3">
      <TabItem Header="FIRST">
            <!-- <ContentOfFirstTabItem/> -->
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem Header="SECOND">
            <!-- <ContentOfSecondTabItem/> -->
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem Header="THIRD">
            <!-- <ContentOfThirdTabItem/> -->
      </TabItem>
</dragablz:TabablzControl>
```

What I have tried so far:

- Implementing `DragEnter` und `PreviewDragEnter` events for each TabItem and for the TabablzControl itself.
- Setting `AllowDrop="True"` for TabablzControl and each TabItem.

Everytime the `e.Source` is equal to the content of the currently selected tab. I'm not able to identify the correct TabItem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy.

You've already prepared the correct setup:

```
<dragablz:TabablzControl DragEnter="TabControl_OnDragEnter" AllowDrop="True">
    <TabItem Header="FIRST"/>
    <TabItem Header="SECOND"/>
    <TabItem Header="THIRD"/>
</dragablz:TabablzControl>
```

`AllowDrop` is `true` and there's a `DragEnter` routed event handler. Note that this is a bubbling event, but you also could use the tunneling `PreviewDragEnter` version.

The magic will happen in the event handler. We need the `OriginalSource` property. However, this will be some `Visual` that represents a `TabItem`, not the `TabItem` itself! You should read about WPF's styling and templating features to get more info about it.
All we need is to get from that representing `Visual` to the actual `TabItem`. We can do it by walking up the visual tree until we find the item:

```
private void TabControl_OnDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Just a sanity check - we need a Visual here
    if (!(e.OriginalSource is Visual v))
    {
        return;
    }

    // DragablzItems will represent our TabItems, so we search for those
    var item = GetParentOfType<DragablzItem>(v);

    // DragablzItem.Content should contain our original TabItem
    if (item != null && item.Content is TabItem ti)
    {
        ti.IsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

And the helper `GetParentOfType` method could look like this:

```
static T GetParentOfType<T>(Visual visual) where T : Visual
{
    DependencyObject parent = visual;
    do
    {
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    } while (parent != null && !(parent is T));

    return parent as T;
}
```